# Which Syntax Highligting to use in vim for structurizr's DSL

Tags: vim, structurizr

[Structurizr](https://github.com/structurizr), a tool that is recommended to design a [c4model](https://c4model.com/), comes with its own [DSL](https://github.com/structurizr/dsl). It looks a bit like this:

```
workspace {

    model {
        user = person "User"
        softwareSystem = softwareSystem "Software System"

        user -> softwareSystem "Uses"
    }

    views {
        systemContext softwareSystem {
            include *
            autolayout
        }

        theme default
    }
    
}
```

and the file extension is `.dsl`. Does anyone know which filetype you have to set in vim in order to get some syntax highlighting? It probably won't be a perfect match but maybe better than nothing. I'm asking, because if you put a file like this to github or gitlab you do get some syntax highlighting, but vim guesses the filetype as `dsl` and the highlighting does not show at all.

Comment: Vim detects .dsl as a dsssl file type and runs .dsl syntax file. However, I do not see syntax highlighting for your example. When I set DTD as a syntax, that looks similar to your example.

Comment: Not sure, but you can try `set ft=ruby` and `set sw=4`. There seems to be quite a syntax overlap between `dsl` and `ruby`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there was no proper syntax for structurizr available in vim, I ended up [providing a dedicated one](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/8764).